# How to access asp validators when calling a webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, user-controls, asmx

I have a user control in which there are some textboxes. There are asp validators associated with each textboxes. 
And when button click I am submitting the textbox values to a web method (in asmx web service) through jQuery AJAX. Normally asp validators is not accessible in web method.
My question is how can I access and validate the asp validators from server side.

Answer (score 0):

As a `webmethod` is `static` you cannot access any of the Page's controls inside a webmethod. However you can try validating it before your AJAX call using,

```
Page_ClientValidate("your_validation_group_name");
if (Page_IsValid)
{
    //TO DO: Make your ajax call
}
```

P.S: In my opinion its better to use [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your response!! But these are of client side validation right ?? I want to ensure my form elements to validate at server side also.What can I do in this case.I have asp validators. But how can I check the validation for those validators for those elements from server side ?